# click hidden element selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i try to click rate use selenium (google map )
i no click i use class name and xpath and nothing
and i try
execute_script
and its same
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('s2xyy')[0].click()")
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH6Q9.png)
i want click and i dont know how can i do it :( any help plz

driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('s2xyy')[0].click()")
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH6Q9.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try using driver.execute_script, and use javascript to click on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute with this xpath:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='s2xyy'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKfWO.jpg)")).click();[image]